# ref doesnt set value to variable in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, ref, use-ref

I've been doing some React crash course and got in a lot of problems.
To start with,

```
observer.current.observe(ElemenentIGotWithRef.current)
```

wasn't working in `useEffect`, because for some reasons the `current` value wasn't set at the first render.

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(ElemenentIGotWithRef)
  }, [])
```

console.log of my ElemenentIGotWithRef:

[image]

I solved it with

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    if (ElemenentIGotWithRef.current)
      observer.current.observe(ElemenentIGotWithRef.current);

    return (()=>{
      observer.current.disconnect();
    })
  }, [ElemenentIGotWithRef.current])
```

But now I am stuck with another function, which doesn't work normally because of my crutch / my unproper `useEffect` work.

How could I make ref set value at the first render?

Comment: This runs **AFTER** the first render   `useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(ElemenentIGotWithRef)
  }, [])`. So you probably want to see why it is not correct in the first render

Answer (score 1):

Usually the element is ready before `useEffect` is called. However, in certain situations (conditional rendering for example), the element is not ready, and the `ref` is not set immediately. The problem with your approach is the setting the `ref.current` with a new value, doesn't cause a re-render, so the `useEffect` might not be called when you want it. In your case, something else causes a re-render (probably the state used for the conditional render), and so you avoid this problem.

You can use `useState` instead of a `useRef` because components also accept a function as a `ref`. That would cause the component to re-render when the state updates with the ref:

```
const [ref, setRef] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
  if (ref) observer.current.observe(ref);

  return () => {
    observer.current.disconnect();
  }
}, [ref])

return (
  <ComponentWithDelayedRef ref={setRef} />
)
```

Another variation on the function as a ref idea, is to create a callback to observe the element, and pass it as the ref:

```
useEffect(() => () => {
  observer.current.disconnect();
}, [])

const observe = useCallback(el => {
  observer.current.observe(ref)
}, []);

return (
  <ComponentWithDelayedRef ref={observe} />
)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I wanted to find a way to make it work with useRef. I have no conditional rendering for this element, so is there any chance conditions for other block could cause such a problem?

Comment: What happens to the element on component mount (first render)?

Comment: It stays undefined, tho I sign value to it through ref = {ElemenentIGotWithRef}